# Прозрачная строка состояния в СollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: android

Как сделать прозрачной строку состояния в СollapsingToolbarLayout, подобно тому как это сделано в ВК?
[image: прозрачная строка]

Comment: https://github.com/jgilfelt/SystemBarTint